# How to print features after modeling in random forest?

Tags: python-2.7

I am modeling a dataset using random forest classifier. I want to print the features that are being selected by random forest.
I have used `feature_importances_` as follows:

```
modelRF.feature_importances_
```

But it is showing the error as:

> NameError: name 'feature_importances_' is not defined

Also on using the "fit" method, It is giving the error as:

> AttributeError: 'RandomForest' object has no attribute 'fit'

Following are the parameters used in random forest classifier:

```
(data, x_cols, y_col, num_trees, method, impurity, max_depth=10, min_instance_per_node=20, min_information_gain=0.01, max_bin=32, feature_subset_strategy=u'auto', seed=123, async_execution=False)
```

I want to print the features that are selected using random forest.

Is there a need to define some additional thing to make the above methods work for random forest?(I am modelling RF in distributed platform using adatao/arimo package).

Answer (score 0):

There is a module named `variable_importance` in arimo package which will give you the features selected by random forest classifier.

It will give a pandas dataframe with `variable name, importance score`

The `variable name` which has `importance score`> 0.0 is the feature selected by random forest classifier.
This can be used for arimo package in python for distributed platform.

```
model.feature_importances_
```

can be used otherwise for other packages.